# How to generate dummy images in PHP Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to make dummy data on my home page, including showing dummy images. How can I generate images?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sample+image&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf-qLXg9fTAhUC54MKHXBWCqoQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=694

Comment: I am Asking about how to make images as dummy data dynamically

Comment: you can make images in  [intervention](http://image.intervention.io/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to look your homepage "live" with dummy images and without actually uploading the image, you can show random images using this site:

http://lorempixel.com/

`<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" />`

You can also store that image path in the database while seeding.

Thanks

Comment: Lorem pixel is no longer available. Try Dummy image https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000

Comment: http://lorempixel.com is dead

Answer (score 10):

In the factory method, while seeding, do something like this.

```
$factory->define(Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
          'image'=>'https://source.unsplash.com/random',

    ];
});
```

Now every time when you run the factory to seed, it will put that link in the image field. This link will give you a random image each time from unsplash.

***Simply add photo dimensions after the URL (ex: /800x600)***

Answer (score 7):

In the following turorial show how to add images in the seeder.
https://www.5balloons.info/faker-images-in-laravel/#

Use the following method:
'image' => $faker->image('public/storage/images',640,480, null, false),

```
<?php 
/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */ 
use App\Product; 
use Faker\Generator as Faker; 
$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->word,
        'short_description' => $faker->sentence,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
        'category_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Category::class)->create()->id;
        }, 
        'amount' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 10000),
        'image' => $faker->image('public/storage/images',640,480, null, false),

    ];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to create a [seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding) file that places some dummy images into your database. Faker comes pre-installed with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

May be it could help someone who wants to work with Ecommerce dummy product images -

```php
public function definition()
{
   $randomImages =[
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41WpqIvJWRL._AC_UY436_QL65_.jpg',
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61ghDjhS8vL._AC_UY436_QL65_.jpg',
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61c1QC4lF-L._AC_UY436_QL65_.jpg',
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710VzyXGVsL._AC_UY436_QL65_.jpg',
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61EPT-oMLrL._AC_UY436_QL65_.jpg',
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71r3ktfakgL._AC_UY436_QL65_.jpg',
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61CqYq+xwNL._AC_UL640_QL65_.jpg',
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71cVOgvystL._AC_UL640_QL65_.jpg',
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71E+oh38ZqL._AC_UL640_QL65_.jpg',
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61uSHBgUGhL._AC_UL640_QL65_.jpg',
        'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71nDK2Q8HAL._AC_UL640_QL65_.jpg'
   ];

   return [
        'name' => fake()->sentence(5),
        'price' => fake()->randomFloat(2, 10, 1000),
        'image' => $randomImages[rand(0, 10)]
   ];
}
```

For me, it's simply enough to get some real-dummy image for development test purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi @Imran, this is long answered but I would like to answer this differently based on tips from laracasts.

- Firstly, you check if the destination folder exists, if not, create it.
- Secondly, generate an image and create a token to act as a delimiter.
- Thirdly, check for the existence of the delimiter in your path using `strpos` function and store the position into `$offset` variable.
- Fourthly, extract your path from the haystack using `substr` function and `$offset` variable as your starting point.

```
private function imageGenerator(): string
{
   $photo_path = storage_path('app/public/profile-photos');
        
   if (!File::exists($photo_path)) {
       File::makeDirectory($photo_path);
   }
        
   $photo_path = $this->faker->image(dir: $photo_path, width: 948, height: 1080);
        
   $token = 'profile';
        
   //$photo_path = $this->faker->image(dir: $photo_path, width: 948, height: 1080, fullPath: false)
   //$photo_path = 'profile-photos/' . $photo_path;
        
  if (($offset= strpos($photo_path, $token)) !== false) {
     $photo_path = substr($photo_path, $offset);
        
     //$photo_path = explode('app/public/', $photo_path, 2)[1];
  }
        
  return $photo_path;
}
```